# Making a good pagination for a grid - extJS

Tags: extjs, grid, pagination, paging

I'm new to ExtJS.
I followed a tutorial with the aim to create a pagination on a grid.
The code was simple, and I found it suspicious...
as result, the paging toolbar is there but there are still all the data displayed on the first load.
Here's my code in the View file :

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{


extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',

alias: 'widget.userlist',

cls: 'overall', 

title: 'xxx <img src="ressource/image/xxx.png" class="title-icon" style= "width: 5%; height: 5%; vertical-align:middle; margin-bottom:0px;" />',

columnLines: true,

dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    store: 'Users',
    pageSize: 2,
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true
}],
```

I also saw tutorial with a var, but I dont' know where to implement it.
I'm sorry I know there is many tutorials about it out of there but I'm struggling on it :(, I don't mastery JS enough !

Thanks by advance ^_^

edit :
My code in my Store file :

```
var itemsPerPage = 2;
var store = Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {

pageSize: itemsPerPage,
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',


proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',

api: {
    read: 'application/data/users.json',
    update: 'application/data/updateUsers.json',
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
    idProperty: 'POC',
        successProperty: 'success',
    totalProperty : 'total'
    }
},
autoLoad: false,

});

store.load({
params:{
   start:0,    
   limit: itemsPerPage
}
});
```

This is telling me : Uncaught TypeError: Object function constructor() { ... has no method 'load'

I tried to remove the store.load, and add {start: 0, limit: 2} after the AutoLoad, according with this http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging.html

With this method, the toolbar shows me " 2-13 data displayed " as it should but there is not data displayed in the grid :'(.

Comment: You need a buffered store for paging. Can you add the code of the Users store to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server-side stack (PHP, .NET, whatever) will need to be aware of the `page`, `start`, and `limit` parameters that are passed through as part of the request. This is what you'll use to create the proper SQL query (or whatever is being done to retrieve the records) to limit the results to match the paging accommodated by the store.

I'm guessing you're getting all the results because your app server is sending back all the results. The paging provided by ExtJS is really just a handshake with whatever code is running on the server...the paging in a remote store isn't limiting the records, your server-side code is. The AJAX request that the store's proxy sends merely tells the server what it expects to receive back as data.

Comment: Thank, I guess that means I have to put something like "store.load({params: {start:0, limit:2}});" somewhere :-) !

Comment: Hey, new issue. I updated my post with my new code. Maybe I need to precise that I'm using a local JSOn file to simulate the data, so no SQL request or so.

Comment: Ah, in that case, maybe try the PagingMemoryProxy: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy

Answer (score 1):

> This is telling me : Uncaught TypeError: Object function constructor()
>   { ... has no method 'load'

The reason it is telling you this is because you are trying to invoke the load() method on the 'class' instead of on an instance:

```
var store = Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
```

[Ext.define](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-define) defines a class. To get an instance, you should call [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-create):

```
var store = Ext.create('AM.store.Users', { /* ... */ });
```

This should happen after the 'class' has been defined, but before you invoke the load.

Maybe you should make it a habit to store the result of Ext.define in a variable with a name starting with an uppercase letter, so you can see it represents a class and not an instance:

```
var Users = Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination in a grid requires a buffered store. Something like this

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

// snip
buffered: true,
pageSize: 5
// snip

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
api: {
    read: 'application/data/users.json',
    update: 'application/data/updateUsers.json',
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'users',
    idProperty: 'POC',
        successProperty: 'success',
        totalProperty: 'yourTotalProperty'
    }
}

});
```

Check the outgoing requests (chrome developer tools, firebug or fiddler). If they add page info (page and pageSize) to the Users-requests then your Ext Js code is correct. And of course you also need a web service that supports paging and delivers the requested data chunks.

Comment: Thanks, but now when I load my page, there is a Loading icon that keep on turning, that's all ^^. Maybe because of the autoLoad:true ? At the moment I only have 15 data to display and I want only 5 by page to test, so it should not take so long to load.

Comment: Do you see the page info in the outgoing requests? And are you served specific pages? Of course, you need the page size now to 5. Your problem should not result (directly) from autoload=true.  I think your problem might come from a missing total property in the proxy. It is here in the api doc http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-totalProperty

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that a buffered store is required for paging. One can have a perfectly normal, non-buffered store that can be used in a grid with a paging toolbar. This example of paging (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/grid/paging.html) is not buffered...

Comment: Hey, I removed the buffered: true and add a totalProperty: total. Now ExtJS knows the number of pages it has to display (14 data = 7 pages shown in the toolbar), but still all the 14 data remain on the same page :(

Comment: Yes, you need to implement code in your server-side app code that will only return 2 records per page.